# mruby and embedded language

Tags: c, mruby

I am learning mruby and one of the arguments in favor of it I am reading everywhere is that it is

```
easily embeddable
```

I have seen some code where C and mruby is mixed. But I am not very clear about what exactly is embeddable language, and what are its advantages? For example I can write everything in C so what does mruby brings into my C application? And why would I like to make this mixture or embedded?

Kindly help me understand with a simple example, here is a sample mruby code embedded into a c code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <mruby.h>
#include <mruby/compile.h>

int main(void)  
{
  mrb_state *mrb = mrb_open();
  char code[] = "5.times { puts 'Ruby is awesome!' }";

  mrb_load_string(mrb, code);
  return 0;
}
```

I am also confusing with embedded systems language and embedded language.

Kindly help me understand this.

Comment: This is not related to "embedded systems". "embedding" has multiple meanings.

Comment: @Olaf what do we mean be embedded in the mruby context ? could you please put an answer on this ?

Comment: Please look up in a dictionary. This is part of your question which is unclear.

Comment: why would we want to embed one language into another ?

Comment: Why do we use C or high-level languages instead of directly typing binary code? This is my last comment&hint. You are expected to show some effort first to solve your problem before asking. And this can be answered with minor effort on your own.